# How to bind img src to data in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, image, webpack, vue.js

I have in my vue webpack script the following:

```
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        repos: [
          {name: 'test1', src: '../assets/logo.png'},
          {name: 'test2', src: '../assets/underscore.png'},
           ...
        ]
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

And then in my html, I'm trying to bind the local src element to an img but I can't get it to work. Here is what my html looks like:

```
<div v-for="repo in repos" :key="repo.name">
  <img :src="repo.src" />
</div>
```

It works fine when my img source is not data-bound such as this:

```
<img :src="../assets/logo.png" />
```

**Why won't my local images load if they are data bound in Vue?**

Here is what my directory looks like:

[image]

Comment: When you inspect the element, what is in `src`?

Comment: ../assets/logo.png

Comment: Is the repo name unique? You show "test" twice here, and you're  using it for `:key`.

Comment: That was a typo I just fixed. The repo names are unique. I was using an id before but for the sake of brevity in this example I changed it.

Comment: You should post an answer details how you fixed problem. That way if someone else is stuck, they can get unstuck.

Comment: If the `src` attribute is set correctly when you inspect the element, then the binding is working correctly. There should be no difference to the DOM how it got set.

Comment: Maybe, but the image isn't displaying still. It's just showing the broken image link. I think it needs to convert the path to base 64 or something like that to find it after the page has been built.

Comment: You need to `require` when you're getting the string from script. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you're using `vue-cli` you have to remember that everything is processed as a module, even images. You'd need to use `require` if the path is relative in JS, like this:

```
{ name: 'test1', src: require('../assets/logo.png') }
```

You can find a lot more details about this here: http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html

Answer (score 9):

simply for binding img src to data, just require the **file address** :

`<img v-bind:src="require('../image-address/' + image data)" />`

example below shows **../assets/logo.png :**

```
<template>
          <img v-bind:src="require('../assets/' + img)" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      img: "logo.png"
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, [vite](https://vitejs.dev/) required a different method to include source file in  like a prop.

The most common way is to use following construction :

```
{ name: 'test1', img: 'new URL(`@/assets/logo.png`, import.meta.url).href' }
```