# Accesing the v-for variable for the src attribute path w/vue

Tags: vue.js

I have a v-for loop in vue. I would like to use the array item value as part my src path like so:

```
<button
          v-for="tab in tabs"
          v-bind:key="tab"
          v-on:click="getSportsData( tab )"
        > 
<img src="./src/img/" + tab + ".png">
</button>
```

In Vue.js:

```
data() {
    return {
      tabs: ["MLB", "NFL", "NBA"],
      won: false,
      etc..
     }
```

I have tried a computed property but no good.I get error that "tab" is not defined. any idea's on how to use the "tab' value for my source path. Thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img v-bind:src="'./src/img/' + tab + '.png'">
```

Comment: correct, however if you have a webpack configuration then you have to do with require ('pathToSrcc')
link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847644/how-to-bind-img-src-to-data-in-vue

Comment: Thank you. I could have sworn I tried that but I guess not. I should have specified also for question that I'm using browsify.