# playing sound onClick event in Vue returns Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to play an mp3 sound when I click on an image, but currently I get this error : `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found`

Why isn't my audio playing and how can I make it play?

my function:

```
 playSound() {
  const sound = new Audio("/src/assets/sounds/openbeersound.wav");
  sound.play();
    }
```

```
  <img
    style="width: 100%;"
    :src="beer.image_url"
    alt="placeholder"
    @click="playSound()"
   />
```

Comment: mp3s end in `.mp3`, not `.wav`. Anyway, try loading the sound when your app loads, not in the click event. Put it in your app's `data`, then use `this.sound.play()` in the handler.

Comment: Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/gxu3faqn/

Comment: Example with loading event: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/8r0Lhwko/

Comment: it works when I add your mp3 url, but not when I load a file from my assets, thanks

Comment: That means the issue is exactly what the error says: your browser doesn't support playing wav files, are you using Chrome by chance? https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#WAVE_PCM

Comment: Yes. The same error appears in Firefox as well. I tried playing an mp3, still the same error.

Comment: In that case it's probably best to provide multiple formats (other than .wav)

Comment: It gives me the same error even with mp3.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's a wav or an mp3, this approach should play both

Comment: It looks like you'll also get that error message if the path to the sound file is wrong; I updated the fiddle so it prints an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the audio is loaded correctly.
[How to bind img src to data in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847644/how-to-bind-img-src-to-data-in-vue)
(images or audio are the same)

[If you want to learn more about it.](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports)

Comment: I have an image binded to the img, do I need to bind audio as well?

Comment: yes, make sure in the network panel that the wav file is loaded correctly and the server don't return a 404