# Dynamically add an img in Nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I want to make a component that gets a String prop with the name of the image

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
      image: String,
    }
)

</script>
```

I tried using the required function as solution given in nuxt but this doesnt work in nuxt 3 and i cant find an alternative

```
<div class="col-4 h-100 text-center">
  <h1>Picture</h1>
  <img :src="require(`../assets/${image}.jpg`)" />
</div>
```

I only tried using a normal src attribute to test if it can find the image and that works.

Comment: You can make a function that returns the image string, and if the string is empty or fail to load, returns an placeholder image.

Comment: Using Vite or Webpack?

Comment: @kissu I'm using Vite

Comment: [This is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71514878/8816585) the way to go. Be careful when using that one because you will need to have either `..` or `.` as your starting point as [mentioned here](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#imports-must-start-with--or-).

Comment: @mathias-van-langendonck check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74762970/tilde-not-convert-to-absolute-path-when-use-it-dynamic/74763017#74763017