# Tilde does not convert to the absolute path when using dynamically

Tags: html, typescript, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I want to create 3 cards dynamically. Each card has an image and I want to set a path dynamically for each of them but I can't use the tilde `~` because the tilde does not convert to the absolute path:

```html
<img
        :src="'~/assets/images/how-to-use/image1.jpg'"
        :alt="part.title"
      />
```

I'm getting this error :

```
GET http://localhost:3000/~/assets/images/how-to-use/image2.jpg 404 (Page not found: /~/assets/images/how-to-use/image1.jpg)
```

I set my `buildAssetsDir` to `example` but I can't even do this :

```html
<img
        :src="'example/assets/images/how-to-use/image1.jpg'"
        :alt="part.title"
      />
```

this code won't work after build time. but why?

Comment: The ~ doesn't represent an absolute path, it represents your user home directory; this will typically not be the same thing on the server as it is on your local machine.

Comment: ty, I thought the `~` should convert to an absolute path by module bundler. I used nuxt2 before. How can I use assets files dynamically? I need something like nuxt2 ` require` function

Comment: Apologies, I missed that this was nuxt; yeah, in that case the `~` should map to the srcDir (which is usually the same as the rootDir), but in your case it seems to be passing straight through to the rendered URL (where it's interpreted as user home.)  Sorry, I'm not well enough versed in nuxt to help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you using vite.
I found this way:

```
<script>
const glob = import.meta.glob("~/assets/images/how-to-use/*", {
  eager: true,
});

const getImageAbsolutePath = (imageName: string): string => {
  return glob[`/assets/images/how-to-use/${imageName}`]["default"];
};
</script>
```

You can pass your `imageName` (don't forget the extension) to this function and get the absolute path.

This way works even after the build.

You can't use this:

```html
<img
  :src="'example/assets/images/how-to-use/image1.jpg'"
  :alt="part.title"
/>
```

but why?

It's because nuxt3 will change the assets file name too, so this path is not correct

#### important notes

1. `require` does not work with vite
2. you can use `import image1Name from '../assets/images/how-to-use/image1.jpg'` and use `image1Name` in your template too.
3. you can always add your images to the public folder
   **these ways work after the build**

Comment: `require` is a Webpack thing, saying that it doesn't work with Nuxt3 is not 100% true. Nuxt3 uses Vite by default, but you can also opt-in with Webpack5. The correct sentence would be to say: "`require` does not work with Vite, which is the default bundler used by Nuxt3".

Comment: Working with when you have to use component and pass image (local path) path from parent to child