# Passing Background Image Path as Props not Working in Nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I have a banner component in which I am passing the props for the `image` `title` and
the `subtitle`. When I set the **image** prop as my background image URL, it does not work.
Here is my component

```html
<template>
  <div class="" :style="`background-image:url(${image})`">
    <div class="content">
      <span class="text-primary">{{ subTitle }}</span>
      <h1 class=" text-grey-700 mt-px-18">{{ title }}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "SharedBanner",
  props: ["title", "subTitle", "image"],
};
</script>
```

This is my parent component

```html
<shared-banner
  title="Listings"
  subTitle="LOREM IPSUM"
  image="assets/images/listingsBanner.png"
/>
```

I believe the issue has something to do with the image path.
Is there a way to set dynamic image paths as props for the style object in Nuxt3?

Comment: I think it's similar to my question you can't use the assets file path dynamically for now read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74762970/tilde-does-not-convert-to-the-absolute-path-when-using-dynamically