# Composition API: strange behavior of a computed property

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am using a computed property (in Vue 3 with the composition API) and binding it to an `img` `src` attribute.

```js
const arrowUrl = computed(() =>
    width.value > thresholds.value.xl
        ? '/img/elements/arrow.svg'
        : '/img/elements/arrow_small.svg'
);
```

```html
<img :src="arrowUrl"></img>
```

When I inspect the first call of the computed property (on load with a breakpoint):

- The `/img/elements/arrow_small.svg` is already displayed.
- It returns `/img/elements/arrow.svg` but it won't display it.

I changed the width of the frame lower than the `thresholds.value.xl` and then I changed it back to the initial width and the right img src (`/img/elements/arrow.svg`) is displayed.

I don't understand why the `arrow_small.svg` is displayed before the first call of the computed property and why when I change the width of the frame it works.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where is your `width` ref sourced from?

Comment: From Vuetify useDisplay()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue 3 Vite - dynamic image src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66419471/vue-3-vite-dynamic-image-src)

Comment: No, I have the same issue