# How to dynamically load image, on build

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

My image are loaded from external request,
I got for loop and it load image in array of name,
But when i build image are not building cause they are not loaded or referenced.
Thanks you

I tried to force the export of my images during build, but i didn't know how to load it correctly in my template if i force them to be building

Comment: Question seems unclear

Comment: I load my image like this : require('@/assets/images/' + getItem(n).image)
But the func depends of my back,
So it didn't load any image at beginning if my back didnt tell "you have to load this image" 
So when i npm run build it didn't build my image

Comment: To load images dynamically, please look at the following link. It has been described completely. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66419471/vue-3-vite-dynamic-image-src?rq=2