# Vuejs component image source concat with a props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, src

I want to display an icon with a name file given from props received from parent component in Vuejs 3.
The icon name comes from a DB via a method getting info.

Here is the part of my script getting props :

```
<script>
export default {
  props: ['id', 'name', 'icon']
}
</script>
```

This code is working well in template (with give name in string) :

```
<img v-bind:src="require('../../assets/icon01.png')" />
```

This code is working well in template (displaying the received icon name) :

```
<br>Icon name : {{ icon }}
```

To add the dynamic image, I tried every combination of :

```
<img v-bind:src="require('../../assets/' + this.icon)" />
<img :src="require(`../../assets/${this.icon}`)" />
<img v-bind:src="require(this.getIconName())" />
```

I tried to add a method to the component methods list to concat and return the full string and use it within the require or even directly.
I tried to use v-bind, v-img, img, everything i could find on the web.

Even a concat like this :

```
<img v-bind:src="require('../../assets/' + 'icon01.png')" />
```

in the require is working fine, as long as this is not with my variable.

I keep getting errors, depending on which version i'm trying.

One of the most usual errors is :

> ERROR in ./src/assets/stop16.ico 1:0
> Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> (Source code omitted for this binary file)

The "stop16.ico" is another icon from the asset folder, i don't know how it's getting it since i am not even using it.

Any idea what could save me ?

Comment: maybe try <img :src="   HERE  require(../../assets/${this.icon}    HERE     )" /> with HERE = ` at the beginning.

Comment: Have you tried without wrapping the pathname with `require()` function ?

Comment: I think you are using Vite, so you can find your answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66419471/vue-3-vite-dynamic-image-src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up with this :

```
<img v-bind:src="require(`../../assets/${this.icon}`)" />
```

And it works now, i don't get why it wasn't working from the start.