# v-for dynamic images src

Tags: laravel, vue.js, carousel

In `resources/images` directory i have 10 images that i want to show through `vue3-carousel` library, the images names are `1.jfif`, `2.jfif`..etc, but the attribute binding doesn't work like this, it gives error : `Property assignment expected.`:

```
        <Slide v-for="slide in 10" :key="slide">
            <div class="carousel__item">
                <img :src="../../images/{{slide}}.jfif" width="500" />
            </div>
        </Slide>
```

i also tried like this, using template string:

```
<img :src="`../../images/${slide}.jfif`" width="500" />
```

but it will then look for images in the `public` directory instead, it give me errors like `/images/2.jfif:1 GET http://localhost/images/2.jfif 404 (Not Found)`

how can i solve that issue? thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue 3 Vite - dynamic image src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66419471/vue-3-vite-dynamic-image-src)

Comment: i moved my images to public folder

Answer (score 0):

You could incode your images in Base64, then you can use it on the bind.

This website will do it for you: https://www.base64-image.de/.

Just upload your images there, click show code and copy whats underneath `For use in <img> elements:`.

Since the base64 encoding is very big, I'd recommend you store in a separated file to keep your code organized.

Example:
images.js

```
const image1 = 'data:image/png;base64...';
const image2 = 'data:image/png;base64...';
const images = [image1, image2];
export default images;
```

Then, you import and use it on the bind accordingly.

```
<Slide v-for="image in images" :key="image">
    <div class="carousel__item">
        <img :src="image" width="500" />
    </div>
</Slide>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 hi to use dynamic images in lock

 // hosturl:'domain website' or 'path like /'

 <Slide v-for="(img, index) in imgaes"> 
 <div class="carousel__item">
 <img alt="img.alt" src="hosturl+'/media/img'+img.src" style="height:100%;width:100%;object-fit: cover;">    
  </div>
  </Slide>

 or 
 
 <Slide v-for="(item, index) in items"> 
  <div class="carousel__item">
  <img :alt="item.name" src="hosturl+'/path_media/'+item.img" style="height:100%;width:100%;object-fit: cover;">    
 </div>
 </Slide>

 --data on returen function exampel--
 
 imgaes: [
 {src: "up362R31381.jpg",alt:"1"},
 {src: "up1376R65296.jpg,alt:"2"),
 {src: "up1376R65296.jpg,alt:"3"),
 {src: "up1376R65296.jpg,alt:"4"),
 {src: "up1376R65296.jpg,alt:"5"),
 {src: "up1376R65296.jpg,alt:"6"),
 {src: "up1376R65296.jpg,alt:"7"),
 {src: "up1376R65296.jpg,alt:"8"),
 {src: "up1376R65296.jpg,alt:"9"),
 {src: "up1376R65296.jpg,alt:"10")
 ]

 or 

 imgaes: ['up1.jpg','up2.jpg=','up3.jpg','up4.jpg','up5.jpg','and_more.jpg']

 or
 hosturl:'link website', 
 items:[
 {name:"slide1",img:"up1.jpg"},
 {name:"slide2",img:"up1.jpg"},
 {name:"slide3",img:"up1.jpg"},
 {name:"slide4",img:"up1.jpg"},
 {name:"slide5",img:"up1.jpg"}
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `require()` function to reference local assets correctly

```html
  <Slide v-for="slide in 10" :key="slide">
      <div class="carousel__item">
          <img :src="require(`@/resources/images/${slide}.jfif`)" width="500" />
      </div>
  </Slide>
```

By wrapping the filepath inside `require()` Webpack which comes bundled with Laravel will handle loading the correct asset during build time.