# Vue.js v-for do no render image

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, v-for

I'm trying to render four images using v-for with a range, 1 to 4.
`v-for="n in 4" :key"n"`
But, using 'n' as part of src does not work. Why?

```
 <div v-for="n in 4" :key="n">
    <img
       :src="`../assets/images/image-product-${n}-thumbnail.jpg`"
       class="rounded-xl h-16 w-16 hover:cursor-pointer"
    />
 </div>
```

Tried using 'key' instead of 'n', converting 'n' to string... none worked

If I hardcorde like this, it works

```
<img
      src="../assets/images/image-product-1-thumbnail.jpg"
      class="rounded-xl h-16 w-16 hover:cursor-pointer"
 />
```

Comment: The error I get is: 
GET
http://localhost:3000/assets/images/image-product-4-thumbnail.jpg
[HTTP/1.1 404 Page not found: /assets/images/image-product-4-thumbnail.jpg 731ms]

Comment: Well, the problem is not related to vue or v-for. Vue is doing what you told him to, as the URL is the error is right. Actually, the error hints you toward what the problem is : the image was not found on your local server.

Comment: Are you sure number 4 is available?

Comment: Yes, the error appears for 1 to 4

Comment: Vue.js questions are highly version specific and should always be tagged with [vuejs2] or [vuejs3].  In the case you're using Vue 3 + Vite please see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66419471/vue-3-vite-dynamic-image-src). The problem is not that the URL is incorrect, but that Vite needs specific help in analyzing dynamic URLs

Comment: This solution worked fine here :D [https://stackoverflow.com/a/73284282/21774784](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73284282/21774784)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I  had the same issue, but the problem is not the path or the @ in the path, I've tried this:

```
    <img class="product-listed" :src="`${product.src}`">

    <button @click="navigateTo(product.id)" class="add-to-cart">Añadir al carrito</button>
   <h4> {{product.name }}</h4>
   <p>{{ product.precio }}</p>
</div>
```

And in the browser DOM this is what I see:

If I place an image manually with the same path, it shows up, but when is inside a dinamically path (v-for) coming from the API, the image does not show up.
By the way Im using Vue JS version Option API.

Also I've tried:
:src="`require(${product.src}`)"
where the product.src is declared in the JSon (API) like following:
{
"name":"product1",
"src":"../assets/img/product2.png",
"precio":"15.50",
"categoryID":1,
"id": "1"
},

And if I console log the product, it has the right path.
and properties.
It works on my local enviroment, maybe it could help you

Comment: Please do not use answers to say you have the same problem/question. Only use answers to post actual solutions/answers to the question being asked.

Answer (score -2):

If you have a **global aliases (@)** available i recommend you to use it.

Because **using relative path** can works in local for example but when the project is compile (build) the **related path can be broken**.

When using dynamic src path you can require it before loading.

With the aliases you can do:

```
:src="`require(@/assets/images/image-product-${n}-thumbnail.jpg`)"
```