# can I use vite alias in a vue function?

Tags: vue.js, vite

Using vue 3.4 and vite 5.1 and I have the standard alias set in my vite.config.ts

```
alias: {
    '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
}
```

So far so good.  Works beautifully. I can do this with no problem:

```
<img src="@/assets/images/image.jpg" alt='an image'>
```

and the image shows up just fine because it is in `./src/assets/images/image.jpg`.

But what I want to do is set bind src to a computed ref since the image will change depending on what the user clicks. That doesn't seem to work though, even when the path is set correctly to "@/assets/images/image.jpg":

```
<img :src="myComputedRef" alt='an image'>
<img :src="myPathFunction()" alt='an image'>
```

Is this just a limitation of vite?  I can see that, because otherwise it would constantly be parsing the files every time the dom changed.

Comment: it is a limitation.  once you switch to dynamic paths you need to use relative paths without aliases.  see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66419471/vue-3-vite-dynamic-image-src)