html5 img doesn't work in Vue3 (path Independent
works <img src="../pic/wh.jpg"> 
doesn’t work  <img src="../src/assets/pic/wh.jpg" >

I created a vue project and migrated the html I wrote earlier to index.html.
I don't know why the image in the index of the vue project can't be imported properly, it works normally in html, I have changed the correct path
and I can open both of them with ctrl + left-click on the path.
No console error
I couldn't find the problem so much that I even restarted the project, rebooted my computer, and cleared the npm cache.
but it still doesn't work...
I want to know why it doesn't work
==============================================
here are my project's pic and index.html’s path
--public--index.html --src--assets--wh.jdg
i add my pic in a navbar，it doesn‘t work like this(
<!-- index.html -->
<nav><img src="../src/assets/pic/wh.jpg" ></nav> 

works in old project like normal img

Both of them are in the nav tag of the body.
i think they are same.
i just change path，and I can open both of them with ctrl + left-click on the path in VSC.
this is my skeleton it's too difficult to descript sry


Path issue. It appears '../pic/wh.jpg' exists wrt your index.html. Make sure '../src/assets/pic/wh.jpg'  path exists.

can you provide more info about your environment?

if you use vite: <img src="@/assets/pic/wh.jpg" >

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66419471/vue-3-vite-dynamic-image-src

i add more info about my project


please set alias in vite.config.js

// ...
resolve: {
      alias: {
        "@": resolve(__dirname, "src"),
      },
    },
// ...

like this use
<img src="@/assets/pic/wh.jpg" >
