Vue 3 image source not found when using v-bind; hard-coding name loads fine
I have a list of sections, each with its own icon.  Within the v-for (root in list) loop, I'm using this code:
<img :src="'/src/assets/images/icons/byCategory/' + root.folder.iconName" />
The page has a 404 error on the icon.
When I hard-code the icon name it loads just fine:
<img src="/src/assets/images/icons/byCategory/Benefits_Icon.png" />
Doing an inspect on the non-working image, the src looks identical to my hard-coded one:
<img src="/src/assets/images/icons/byCategory/Benefits_Icon.png">
Both images are in the same place of code, so they have the same parent classes.
Does anyone have any idea on why the directive isn't finding the icon?
UPDATE------
As @BorisMaslennikov suggested, the linked question in the comments is probably my issue as well.
I am tasked with upgrading legacy Vue2 code.  I am now using Vue 3.4.15 along with Vite 4.4.5, but we are still using the Options API.  I will need to work on getting the given solution converted from Composition.

would be great to have more code + your environment setup. can you also provide which url requests your browser? if you open it in new tab will you get 404 as well?

this post might also help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66419471/vue-3-vite-dynamic-image-src

@BorisMaslennikov, the question you linked is most likely my issue as well.  I have updated the question to include that information.  Thank you.

could you please provide browser request info when it requests image? I'm interested in URL
