How to use Astro's Image in a Vue.JS component?
I would be able to use Astro's image in my Vue.JS component so I can import them from assets folder and benefit from performance improvements of it's rendering.
Before using Vue.JS I was doing something like this:
 regions.map((region: any) => (
    <Image src={import(region.image)} 
 ));

Now that component is made in Vue.JS like:
 <a v-for="(region, index) in displayedRegions"
        :key="region.name"
        :href="region.url"
        target="_blank"
        class="block"
        :aria-label="`Vai al gruppo della regione: ${region.name}`" >

      <img :src="region.image" :alt="region.name"
            class="absolute inset-0 h-full w-full object-cover transition duration-300 ease-in-out group-hover:scale-110" />
</a>

The images are set in /assets/images so while the first case was working as expected, the second one does not.

It's unclear what the project looks like. Is it still using Astro? A generic way in Vue is to calculate a collection so it already contains imported image. Anything else requires custom comp or the support from build tool. Since Vue computeds are synchronous and dynamic imports are async, it could be something like watch(displayedRegionsRef, async (regions) {  regionsWithImagesRef.value = await Promise.all(regions.map(async (region) =>  ({...region, image: (await import(region.image).default) })).  This depends on your case and whether there are solutions that are more idiomatic to astro

I mean if displayedRegions stays static during component lifespan, it's easier to make setup async and import images once instead of a watcher

@EstusFlask, I will give it a bit more context, the project uses Astro, while I have a component written in Vue called RegionList, the regions are imported from a static JSON file and the regin.image points to a file in assets/images, I was wondering if it was possibile to combine the v-for and the Astro's Image:assets

If the list of images is known on comp setup then do once in setup const images = await ... import(imagePath), or use Astro.glob() if it suits you. I'm unaware of the possibility to use astro comps (astro:assets), so for vue-only solution this is it. Since Astro uses Vite, there's also this option https://stackoverflow.com/a/76104080/3731501 , but I can't say how well it will play with Astro, I don't use it much

@EstusFlask I've ended by using a pure Vue solution without the Astro:assets so I just use a simple <img /> and I move the images in the public folder to make them accessible to Vue.

Probably the solution with getImageUrl  will work equally good and easy

@EstusFlask it give it a try, ty :)
