# Vue 3 dynamic image

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, src

I am using a v-for to load data on cards.  The image is not showing up and not sure why.
I though `:src = "'item.img'"` or `:src = "{{item.img}}"` would work, but neither are working.

Here is my code

```
 <div v-for="(item, index) in basicData" :key="index">
      <transition class="slide">
        <div v-if="index >= start && index < end" class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{item.title}}</h5>
            <img
              :src="'item.img'"
              class="card-img-top"
              :alt="'item.img'"
              style="margin: 20px 5px"
            />
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </transition>
```

and here is the screen shot

[image]

When I hard code `src="../assets/featured/pizzaOne.jpeg"`
the image appears.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind img src to data in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847644/how-to-bind-img-src-to-data-in-vue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create method or computed property:

```
methods() {
  getImage(imagePath) {
    return require(imagePath);
  }
}
```

Then in template call that method:

```
<img
  :src="getImage(item.img)"
  class="card-img-top"
  :alt="item.img"
  style="margin: 20px 5px"
/>
```

Comment: I am getting an Error: Cannot find module '../assets/featured/pizzaOne.jpeg'.  When I hard code in  '../assets/featured/pizzaOne.jpeg'. the image show up

Comment: yes they are in the src/assets folder and I created a subfolder featured. Here is the relative path src/assets/featured/pizzaOne.jpeg

Comment: The question is clear duplicate of existing and already answered question. You should always first search for duplicates and if the duplication is clear (as in this case) mark it as duplicate instead of answering...